# mousePressed() on a button to change gameStates

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to change the gameStates with a button pressed, this doesn't seem to be working. The error appears to be that, "startButton.mousePressed is not a function".

```
function draw(){ 
    if (gameState === "start"){
        startButton.mousePressed(() => { stateChange() });
    }
}

function stateChange() {
  gameState = "playing";
}
```

I am also familiar with making buttons with html but the use of `mousePressed()` doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: how do you initialize the `startButton` variable?

Comment: I don't reckon mousepressed as a function. I think you are looking at mousedown event?

Comment: can you include HTML code here ?!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it correctly startButton is an HTML element and you want to trigger stateChange function every time startButton is clicked. There are two DOM events which can be used.

[onmousedown](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousedown.asp):

This will be triggered when any of the mouse button is clicked(left, right, center)

[onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp):

This will be triggered only on the left click.

you can find usage info for both in the links provided.